# utilizando "maps.googleapis.com/maps/" da error

Tags: android

Estoy intentando grafitar una ruta con varios puntos. Lo he visto en varios videos y todo ellos para calcular la ruta me dirigen a esta pagina:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=xx.xxxxxx,-x.xxxxxx&destination=xx.xxxxxx,-x.xxxxxx

donde se supone que me dice los datos de la ruta pero me sale un error que me dice:

"You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to [http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account"](http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account%22)

Vamos que necesito una clave API. Se supone que la clave API ya la tengo a la hoar de hacer el mapa. ¿Como lo soluciono?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En tu url debes de pasarle también tu API Key válida, por ejemplo:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=xx.xxxxxx,-x.xxxxxx&destination=xx.xxxxxx,-x.xxxxxx&key=AIzaSyCKyVbBzwtgkyuut7P5mxK9vcOWMygCfp0

Comment: Hola, Lo he puesto tambien y me dice esto:

Answer (score 0):

Lo he puesto tambien y me dice esto:
"This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, with empty referer"

Comment: ¿Hay que crear obligatoriamente una cuenta de facturacion con tarjeta de credito para que esto funcione?